# Looping in associative array with conditions

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I have wcf web service returns daily news in json object which i convert to associative array, and i want to loop through this array to get certain data depending on some conditions (like get array when its date field = today and ignore the other data with another dates).

So I need to know how I can loop through the main array and divided it with conditions to finally get needed data.

Or if there is any other method to loop through the json object without converting to associative array?

Here is the array structure:

```
{"GetDailyNewsResult":
{
    "IsError": false,
    "ErrorMsg": "",
    "DailyNews": [
        {
            "Date": "2016-04-18",
            "LanguageID": "2",
            "OuterTopic": "5",
            "ReminderSectionID": "3",
            "ReminderPhraseNo": "2",
            "DailyNewsSections": [
                {
                    "SectionID": "1",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "1",
                    "Phrase": "sergbsvbzxcvbcgh",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "2",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "2",
                    "Phrase": "fghdfyhdfgnbxc",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "3",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "3",
                    "Phrase": "dfeasertadsrtg",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "4",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "4",
                    "Phrase": "dfgbzxcvzxcv",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "5",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "5",
                    "Phrase": "sghdfgbxcvb",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "6",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "6",
                    "Phrase": "sdfagdvbxcvb",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "7",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "7",
                    "Phrase": "asdasdasd",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Date": "2016-04-19",
            "LanguageID": "2",
            "OuterTopic": "5",
            "ReminderSectionID": "3",
            "ReminderPhraseNo": "2",
            "DailyNewsSections": [
                {
                    "SectionID": "1",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "1",
                    "Phrase": "jhmdfadrtgdfgfgh",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "2",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "2",
                    "Phrase": "asdfretfncvb",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "3",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "3",
                    "Phrase": "asdfgvbnvbn",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "4",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "4",
                    "Phrase": "dfghfgrrthsdvbc",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "5",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "5",
                    "Phrase": "dghdfghdfgh",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "6",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "6",
                    "Phrase": "ghdgfhdfgh",
                }
                {
                    "SectionID": "7",
                    "Header": "test",
                    "PhraseNo": "7",
                    "Phrase": "dfghdfghfdgh",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep the data as JSON Object? If you turn it into a `json_decode($json, true));` you could loop through the data just as you would with any other array.

If you want to know how to loop through the array please provide more info about the data structure and what you want to do with it.

Comment: edited and add the array structure, i need to extract the news of today and extract certain section by SectionID and the news with exact language by LanguageID. My question is how to loop through the array with conditions ??